# Adding a 1 bit flag in a 64 bit pointer

Tags: c++

If you define a union for traversing a data structure squentially (`start` and `end` offset) or via a pointer to a tree structure depending on the number of data elements on a 64 bit system where these unions are aligned with cache lines, is there a possibility of both adding a one bit flag at one of those 64 bits in order to know which traversal must be used and still allowing to reconstruct the right pointer?

```
union {
    uint32_t offsets[2];
    Tree<NodeData> * tree;
};
```

Comment: You can use the least significant bit of the pointer (chances are, you'd never get an odd pointer because `new` returns addresses aligned at 2, 4, or 8). The "payment" for this is storing `offset<<1` in the offsets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's system dependent, but I don't think any 64-bit system really uses its full pointer-length yet.
Also, if you know your data is 2<sup>n</sup>-aligned, chances are those n bits are just sitting idle there (On some old systems they just would not exist. But I don't think any of those were 64-bit systems, and anyway they are no longer of interest).

As an example, x86_64 uses 48bits, the upper 16 must be the same as bit47. (sign-extended)
Another example, ARM64 uses 49bits (2 mappings of 48bit at the same time), so there you only have 15 bits left.

Just remember to corect the pilfered bits. (You might want to use `uintptr_t` instead of a pointer, and convert after the correction.)

Using a mis-aligned or impossible pointer causes behavior ranging from silent auto-correction, ranging over silent mis-behavior, to loud crashes.

Comment: so left shifting one bit will do no harm?

Comment: The least significant bit is another choice: I've never seen a system on which `new` would return an odd pointer.

Comment: uintptr_t seems indeed cleaner

Comment: don't shift the valuable bits, just find the bits you might use. Or, if you use `uintptr_t` (certainly preferred), munge them however you want, just restore them before converting back.

Comment: does the reinterpret_cast conversion introduces a lot of overhead?

Comment: Actually, it's a pure compile-time-construct: No instructions generated.

Comment: One way to implement this would be to use a C++ class with public methods for returning both a `uintptr_t` and a `bool`.  The de-munging could then neatly be encapsulated in those methods and perhaps lead to fewer potential errors.